# Add single quote to input procedure argument while using in select query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to add single quote to my input variable in procedure being used in select query.

```
 create or replace procedure listobj(objnam varchar)
    is
    cursor c1 is
    select object_id,object_name,tablespace_name,owner from dba_objects where object_name=objnam;
    rec c1%rowtype;
    begin
    for rec in c1 loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.object_id||'  '||rec.tablespace_name||'  '||rec.owner);
    end loop;
   end;
   /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LISTOBJ (
     OBJNAM   VARCHAR2)
IS
     CURSOR C1(OBJ_NM VARCHAR2)
     IS
          SELECT OBJECT_ID,
                 OBJECT_NAME,
                 --TABLESPACE_NAME,
                 OWNER
            FROM ALL_OBJECTS
           WHERE OBJECT_NAME = OBJ_NM ;

     REC                           C1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
     --Pass the input variable to cursor like a paramater. No need to add single quotes then
     FOR REC IN C1(OBJNAM)
     LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (   REC.OBJECT_ID
                                || '  '                              
                               -- || REC.TABLESPACE_NAME
                                || '  '
                                || REC.OWNER);
     END LOOP;
END;
```

Execution:

```
 SQL> Exec  LISTOBJ('DEPT');
      51149    SCOTT

      PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks!    If I use like input argument with quotes it works however just typing t1 doesn't workSQL> exec listobj('T1');
32070  SYS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec listobj(t1);
BEGIN listobj(t1); END;

              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'T1' not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Thanks Xing! yes, I got it - this won't accept argument without quotes. I don't see accept / vote button - not sure -could you please suggest - and thanks for your response